# Using dynamically created names in sumif function within a LET function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I have data that looks as follows: (obviously much larger...)

| Date | Customer | Amount | Agent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/01/2023 | David B | 200 | Louis |
| 10/01/2023 | Jimmy R | 1500 | Gene |
| 11/01/2023 | David B | 350 | Louis |

I'm trying to make a dynamic report from that table as follows:

- Filter the table by agent
- Get unique names of customers
- Total all sales by customer

(I know I can do this easily with a pivot table, but there is a reason why I want to use dynamic arrays instead)

Here is the formula that I am trying to use:

```
=LET(tbl, FILTER(mainTableRange,TableColumn=AgentName),
dateCol, CHOOSECOLS(tbl,1),   nameCol, CHOOSECOLS(tbl,2), amountCol, CHOOSECOLS(tbl,3),
names, UNIQUE(nameCol),
totalV,  SUMIF(nameCol,names,amountCol),
totalV)
```

And, eventually, I would want to end it with: `HSTACK(names, totalV)` (and other dynamic columns as well)

All variables return the correct information, however when I put them together in the sumif function, it returns value errors.
If I use the actual ranges instead, e.g., `SUMIF(Q12:Q124,names,R12:R124)` then it works fine.

Why is the SUMIF function not working with the LET variables?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful as well. MMULT as a workaround to using arrays instead of ranges https://superuser.com/a/1814816/1856315 (especially read the bottom part of the answer).

Comment: Thanks - looks like it would work but I can't seem to wrap my head around `MMULT`, at least not in my scenario...

Comment: Using your logic (including the names):
`=LET(tbl, FILTER(mainTableRange,TableColumn=AgentName),
dateCol, CHOOSECOLS(tbl,1),   nameCol, CHOOSECOLS(tbl,2), amountCol, CHOOSECOLS(tbl,3),
names, UNIQUE(nameCol),
totalV,  HSTACK(names,MMULT(N(TOROW(nameCol)=names),SEQUENCE(ROWS(nameCol))^0)),
totalV)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `SUMIFS()` only works with pure cell ranges, not values output by other formula. Try in this way-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B10,D2:D10=G2)),
y,MAP(x,LAMBDA(t,SUMIFS(C2:C10,B2:B10,t,D2:D10,G2))),
HSTACK(x,y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason why a `LAMBDA()` helper is needed here, when I tried using the below formula it works wihtout any issues, and the reason is we are using the array in **`criteria`** of `SUMIF()` or `SUMIFS()`, also any `IF()`s family wont work with an array if its considered for the range, but it does works with the criteria.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F4</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B10,D2:D10=G1)),
     HSTACK(a,SUMIF(B2:B10,a,C2:C10)))
```

---

However, with recent updated in `MS365` for Beta Channel users can also use `GROUPBY()` or `PIVOTBY()`

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(B2:B10,C2:C10,SUM,,0,,D2:D10=G1)
```

---

Or,

```
=PIVOTBY(B2:B10,,C2:C10,SUM,,0,,,,D2:D10=G1)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a, UNIQUE(HSTACK(B2:B10,SUMIFS(C2:C10,D2:D10,G1,B2:B10,B2:B10))),
     FILTER(a, TAKE(a,,-1)<>0))
```

---

Alternatively, with <kbd>MMULT()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, HSTACK(B2:B10,MMULT((G1=D2:D10)*(B2:B10=TOROW(B2:B10)),C2:C10)),
     UNIQUE(FILTER(α, TAKE(α,,-1)<>0)))
```

---

Comment: Correct, no need for lambdas here. I already wrote in my original post that the actual range works fine. I marked the answer correct because he pointed out to me the difference between **array** and **range** and that some functions only accept ranges.

Comment: @DaveyD posted an alternative with `MMULT()` as well. Just for note `MAP()` also doesnt work with `SUMIFS()` or `SUMIF()` since the given array is used in criteria its working, if you have the given array for criteria range then you would be needing to use `Thunks` **[Read Here](https://www.flexyourdata.com/blog/what-is-a-thunk-in-an-excel-lambda-function/)** or `MAKEARRAY()` Function.